# Getting Linux interface traffic 64bit statistics in userspace

Tags: interface, traffic, nic

I would like to get the NIC driver **64bit statistics** in **userspace**, in the simplest way possible.
The man page of  API function getifaddrs(), suggests a simple example program that does it using 32bit "**struct rtnl_link_stats**" (possible to see it here for example: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).

The problem with this struct is obvious: the 32bit variables wrap-around (exceed 2^32) quickly (e.g. "**rx_bytes**").

In the same header file ([linux/if_link.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/if_link.h)) that contains **struct rtnl_link_stats**, there is a similar struct with 64bit variables: **struct rtnl_link_stats64**.
I was sure that I'm very close to have the same statistics on 64bit variables, but unfortunately, I failed doing so.

There are functions like **dev_get_stats()**, but they are all written for kernel-space.

Programs like "**ethtool -S**" show these statistics in 64bit values, but I think they do some manipulation and not fill up **struct rtnl_link_stats64** in a simple way.

Reading directly from **/sys/class/net/ethX/statistics/rx_bytes** (using fopen, fscanf...) is ok, but it doesn't perform as good as reading using API.

Is there a simple way **in userspace** to have **struct rtnl_link_stats64** filled with the relevant statistics, that I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the best (performance wise) way I found is using netlink APIs from library libnl.

Here is a link to a simple example program that I found, that implements it:
https://gist.github.com/beejeebus/cc4fb07472cf5a0afd41